# use strict; behaviour not working as expected in Perl wrt $a and $b

Tags: perl

I have written a sample perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$a=1;
$b=2;
if($b==2) {
    $a=3;
}
print $a;
```

Ideally, when I run this code, it should give an error as 'Global symbol "$a" requires explicit package name...'
But it is not giving any error. It gives the output as '3'.
Why so? As far as I know, if we use strict, then we need to define the scope of the variable otherwise it gives an error.
Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: The selected answer explains why the `strict` pragma does not apply to `$a` and `$b` . A syntax checker like [`Perl::Critic`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic) can remind you not to use `$a` and `$b` in an ordinary function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$a` and `$b` are special variables, and thus are not rising error when used with `strict`.

From [`perldoc strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html),

> Because of their special use by sort(), the variables $a and $b are exempted from this check.